# New to C#, having trouble with calculations with C# enums and casting

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xunit

I'm new to C# and having some difficulty figuring out why my unit tests on this one function keep failing.

I have an enum (this is all examples, but you get the gist):

```
public enum TeamActions 
{
   TeamWasScoredAgainst = - 10,
   TeamScored = 10
}
```

I then have a static `TeamHelper` class which calculates a `long` of TeamScore on my `Team` object by evaluating whether or not the `TeamAction` is a positive value or not, so I know whether to add or subtract from the running `TeamScore` total.

```
public class Team
{
  public long TeamScore {get; set;}
}

public static long CalcNewTeamScore(Team team, TeamActions teamAction)
{
    if (team == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Team is null");
    if ((int)teamAction < 1)
    {
       return team.TeamScore - Convert.ToInt64((int)teamAction);
    }
    else
    {
       return team.TeamScore + Convert.ToInt64((int)teamAction);
    }
}
```

My `xUnit` test, which fails is:

```
public void TeamWasScoredAgainst_ShouldDecreaseScore()
{
    // arrange
    var teamUnderTest = new Team
    {
      TeamScore = 100
    };

    // act
    teamUnderTest.TeamScore = TeamHelper.CalcNewTeamScore(teamUnderTest, TeamAction.TeamWasScoredAgainst);

    // assert
    Assert.Equal(90, teamUnderTest.TeamScore);
}
```

I'm really not sure if my test is wrong (first time doing it), or the TeamHelper method casts are wrong, or the math is wrong itself. Any help?

Comment: This is a really weird use of enums. A more common pattern would be `const` fields.

Comment: If it's a const, I wouldn't be able to change the numerical values.

Comment: You also can't change the int value of an enum without recompiling, so I don't see what differs there. I'd suggest looking up what enums are and how they're intended to be used, because like I said, the way you're using them is *really* odd.

Comment: so you'd use a separate class with just a bunch of const's in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your maths are wrong.

Since your enum value itsself is already negative, subtracting it from something else, actually increases the result.

You should change

```
public static long CalcNewTeamScore(Team team, TeamActions teamAction)
{
    if (team == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Team is null");
    if ((int)teamAction < 1)
    {
       // Convert.ToInt64((int)teamAction) = -10
       // you actually have 100 - (-10) => 110
       return team.TeamScore - Convert.ToInt64((int)teamAction);
    }
    else
    {
       return team.TeamScore + Convert.ToInt64((int)teamAction);
    }
}
```

to

```
public static long CalcNewTeamScore(Team team, TeamActions teamAction)
{
    if (team == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Team is null");    
    return team.TeamScore + Convert.ToInt64((int)teamAction);    
}
```

The problem in your code is that `teamAction` can be negative and you subtract negative values. If you subtract a negative value from a number, the result is higher than the number you subtracted from.

A shorter sample to show the problem:

```
var negativeValue = -10;
var result = 10 - negativeValue;
Assert.Equal(20, result);
```

This is just like maths work in real world aswell.

```
x = 10 - (-10)
x = 10 + 10
x = 20
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I wanted the enums to be negative so I could have a log of all the positive or negative transactions that took place.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does exactly what you programmed it to do.

If I would take a guess, I'd say you wanted to subtract 10 when your team loses.

But what you did was add this extra `if` that makes sure that when the enum is *negative*, it gets *subtracted*. But if you subtract "-10" from something, you are effectively adding 10.

"X - (-10)" is "X + 10".

So you probably want to remove this `if` alltogether and always add the enum value. That will substract 10 when the enum value is -10.